# CakePHP user session not updating but database yes

Tags: database, session, cakephp

I'm developing with cakePhP and I have the following problem:

When a user logs in with his name and password to the account system that I've created, he can save items (images) as favorites. This is saved in a text field into the database. What is saved is the image ID.

The saving process works perfectly, the user clicks on the images and they're added to that field (it actually saves all the IDs as a text array that I process later).

The problem comes when removing images. When the user does it (I'll post the code below), the images is removed correctly from the database (I go to PHP MyAdmin and I see it). This means that the array that holds the favorite images IDs is updated instantly. However, when I reload that array from the website, it hasn't been updated. It's like it's stored in the caché or something. Then, if the user logs out and logs in again, then he can see the correct one. The thing is that I have other things in my website that work in a similar way and they all get updated instantly, so I can't see why this doesn't.

This is the code that I use to remove the ID from the database:

```
function remove_favorite($pictureID) {

    $this->User->id = $this->Auth->User('id'); //We get the ID of the current user

    $favoritesArray = $this->User->deleteFavoritePicture($this->User->id, $pictureID); //This function retrieves the array (string) of pictures from the user's table, and deletes all the images with the ID passed as parameter, returning the updated array (string)

    $fields = array('images_favorites' => $favoritesArray, 'modified' => true); //We indicate the field that we're going to update in the users table

    //We save the new string that doesn't contain the deleted image anymore
    if($this->User->save($fields, false, array('images_favorites'))) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The image has been removed from your favorites', true));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Error removing image from favorites, please try again', true));
    }

    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'manage_favorites',$this->User->id));
}
```

This is how the **deleteFavoritePicture** function looks like:

```
function deleteFavoritePicture($userID, $pictureID) {

        $userInfo = $this->find("id = $userID");

        $favoritePicturesString = $userInfo['User']['images_favorites'];
        $favoritePicturesArray = explode(",", $favoritePicturesString); //Array

        $i = 0;
        while ($i < count($favoritePicturesArray)) {
            //We remove from the array the images which ID is the one we receive to delete
            if ($favoritePicturesArray[$i] == $pictureID) unset($favoritePicturesArray[$i]);
            $i++;
        }

        $favoritePicturesString = implode(",", $favoritePicturesArray); //String
        return ($favoritePicturesString);
    }
```

That's it. Does anyone now what can be going on? Thanks so much in advance for any clue!

**EDIT**

Ok, I think I found something that may give a clue of what's going on here:

This is the code for the `manage_favorites` action:

```
function manage_favorites($id) {

    //$user = $this->User->find("id = $id");
    $user = $this->Auth->user();

    $this->set('user', $user);
}
```

That is the action that is called for the page when a user wants to modify his favorites. The same action is called once the user removes a favorite. Here's the thing:

If I use the `$id` parameter in the `manage_favorites` function and the `$user = $this->User->find("id = $id");` line (the one quoted now), then the problem does not exist! This is how I used to have it. **HOWEVER**, I had to change it because it was a big security flaw, since the user id ($id) was a visible parameter who anyone could change, and then access other users accounts. What I did was changing the way I obtain the user array of favorite images, using the following line: `$user = $this->Auth->user();`. This is how I have it now (well, and also without the $id parameter in the function header), so the user information (including the favorites array) comes from the `Auth` component, instead directly from the database.

So, the problem is clear: when the user deletes a favorite, it's doing it on the array in the database. WHen I show the result of that operation, the array I'm retrieving is not the one in the DB, it's the one in the **session**. That's why it's not showing the changes.

How can I avoid this without using a non-secure method like the one I had before?

Comment: What does the `deleteFavoritePicture()` method look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save, the array passed to the `save` method of the model should look like this:

```
[User] => array(
    [field] => value,
    [field2] => value2,
    ...
)
```

In your example, you clearly haven't added the `[User]` key.

Also, is your `modified` field actually the default Cake `modified` field? That is, the DATETIME field which changes to the current time when the row is updated?

Lastly, maybe you have debugging set to 2 in config.php. try changing this to 0 (as in production) and see if caching persists.

Hope some of the points I have mentioned above will solve your problem. Please let me know!

Comment: @linkyndy: thank you for your reply. About the **User** key, I set it at the beginning with `$this->User->id = $this->Auth->User('id');`. I believe this works fine, because the database is correctly updated, in the correct row. The modified field, I have it exactly as you say. I've also tried setting the debugging to 0 (yeah, it was set to 2), but still the same problem happens. My problem seems to be some caché or session problem, because when the code is executed, the Database is updated correctly, It's just that those changes are not reflected until the user logs out and logs in again...

Comment: @linkyndy: I edited my post, I found a clue of what can be happening, could you take a look to the **Edit** part and see if you have a solution for that? Thank you!

Comment: OK, here's the problem: when you log in, Auth stores the logged in user's row from the database (with the data the user had in that moment). Then, on each `$this->Auth->user()`, Cake retrieves the Session user record, the one mentioned above. This is how Auth works. And this is why it works for you only after a re-login: because the Session is renewed with the updated user record. So, in order to get this going, you have to select the user like so: `$user = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));`.

Comment: [...continued from the above comment] This way, you get the current logged in user id from the Session (by using Auth's `user()` method) and fetch this user's database record (with the latest data). Hope this will work for you.

Comment: @linkyndy: Yeah, that's actually what I figured out when I realized what the problem was, I had the answer in front of my but I couldn't see it ;) Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There could be two things wrong with this.

1. What does your `deleteFavoritePicture` method look like?  There could be something being done wrong there.
2. You're passing `false` as the second parameter to the `User::save` method, which means that you don't want to validate.  Unless there is a SQL error, then this will return true even if it doesn't validate properly, I believe.  Try changing this `false` to `true` and see if your results differ.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've edited the post and added the `deleteFavoritePicture` function code. I believe it works well, because the new string saved to the database is correct. The problem is that this change is not reflected in the website until the user logs out and logs in again... About your second point, I just tried setting it to `true`but the same happens...

Comment: I edited my post, I found a clue of what can be happening, could you take a look to the **Edit** part and see if you have a solution for that? THank you!